# How to get Order details in the model of custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

Im creating a module to send the order details to another server's database when a order is placed in my magento server. Im using  event to point to the model class but Im not able to get the order details like product name, quantity, price etc which are all needed to write in the other database. How can I make my model to get the values and write it to the database?

This is the config.xml file Im using

```
       <events>
            <sales_order_invoice_pay>
                <observers>
                    <sendorder>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>xxxx_SendOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderInvoicePay</method>
                    </sendorder>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_pay>
        </events>
```

and this is the code Im using to get the order details

```
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $invoice=$event->getInvoice();
        $order =$invoice->getOrder();   
        $orderno=$order->getIncrementId();
```

I need to get the details of the order placed by customer and then push those details to another server's dd

Comment: please show some code you have so far so we can build on that.

Comment: I have'nt started on model yet. I have created config.xml

Comment: then how can you say you cannot get the order details if you haven't written any code? You can't get them without coding :)

Comment: haha. not Like that. Im hoping to get a code to retrieve last order info somehting like $event = $observer->getEvent();
  $invoice=$event->getInvoice();
  $order =$invoice->getOrder(); 
  $orderno=$order->getIncrementId();
can i get the order details like price etc from it?

Comment: I have edited the qn Marius. Hope it has the necessary details :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the order object you can get the order items like this:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) { //or $order->getAllVisibleItems()

   $price = $item->getPrice();
   $name = $item->getName();
   $qty = $item->getOrderedQty();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have last order id or increment id use the below code to collect last order data

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->loadByIncrementId([increment_id]); //increment id 

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->load([order_id]);     //entity_id
```

From order data you can get shipping data refer below

```
//get shipping method
$shippingMethod = $order->getShippingMethod();
```

For billing address

```
//get billing address
$shippingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
```

To get last order customer details

```
//customer name
$order->getCustomerName();

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->load($order->getCustomerId());
```