# Get Order Id from Item Id in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, items

I am having puchased item id and I need to grab order details in magento 1
Can anybody please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Order details in the model of custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45329/how-to-get-order-details-in-the-model-of-custom-module)

Comment: check my answer will help you to do it by Magento way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by magento way:

```
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load(259283);
echo $orderItem->getOrderId();
```

Comment: I have update my answer as per your sql.

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it.. by this

```
SELECT order_id FROM `sales_flat_order_item` WHERE `item_id` = 259283
```

Comment: why you want to write the sql this way , Magento have its own predefined getters